# Powerful presentation app that allows animating slides

Tags: osx, animation, presentation

I've been using [Apple Keynote](http://www.apple.com/mac/keynote/) for the past few years. Very effective, very powerful. It's my go-to presentation app. However, I need something more powerful than Keynote, in a sense that I can animate slides instead of being still at a time, more advanced control over slide transition animations, and so on.

I've tried the following:

- Microsoft PowerPoint
- Google's Presentation App
- Prezi

And none so far has been able to deliver Keynote's flexibility and power, let alone more advanced animation tools.

Preferably an app that professionals use, like what Google uses in their I/O, or Samsung in their keynotes, and so on.

I use macOS Sierra, and I have a very flexible budget that should cover any presentation tool.

Comment: I see you moved this question here from [productivity.se] (and deleted it there), yet my warning about making a list of requirements seems to not have landed. http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I agree with Jan: Please take a look at [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185), and then [edit] your question accordingly. That will dramatically increase your chances for good answers.