# Alternative to Prezi

Tags: gratis, web-apps, animation, hosted

[Prezi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prezi) recently became a paid service.

Is there another online tool allowing me to create presentations in Prezi’s style?

Prezi can be used to create presentations by moving a "camera" around a 2D canvas, I would like to be able to do the same thing.

Prezi also has a website for hosting presentations and allowing public viewing of these presentations, I would also like an app with this feature.

Comment: Duplicate of http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35990/powerful-presentation-apps

Comment: @Nobody not it isn't. Prezi is very different from powerpoint. I am specifically looking for presentation software that moves a camera through a canvas.

Comment: What do you need/like about Prezi, what OS(es)? Please provide more details.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I like/need the **"moving a 'camera' around a 2D canvas"** feature of prezi as well as its **"website for hosting presentations and allowing public viewing"** and I clearly state I want a [tag:web-apps] solution. Why haven't you read the question?

Comment: I don't know abot tthe camera thing, but you coudl search through http://alternativeto.net/software/prezi/?license=free

Comment: Are there any other alternatives you are looking for sir apart from the already given below?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there **very excellent** free alternatives to Prezi, below is one such example:

[Focusky](https://focusky.com/focusky-free-prezi-alternative.php)

> Focusky, a user-friendly platform to help you create non-linear
>   multimedia presentations with animation effects. Moreover, this online
>   presentation creator can even make it easier and faster for you to
>   share and distribute your online presentations.

- Easy and Familiar
- Create animated presentations in a mind-mapping style
- 3D Transition Effects
- Online & Offline Sharing
- desktop client available

You can also take a look at this video describing [Focusky](https://youtu.be/yUM-ZxQpIR8)

Hope this helps

Comment: And it has a free version too! But it is a desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Sozi. It's a free client side software.

> Sozi is a zooming presentation editor and player. Unlike in most
>   presentation applications, a Sozi document is not organised as a
>   slideshow, but rather as a poster where the content of your
>   presentation can be freely laid out. Playing such a presentation
>   consists in a series of translations, zooms and rotations that allow
>   to focus on the elements you want to show.

http://sozi.baierouge.fr/

Answer (score 0):

I had to split my answer into two, because the two are unique and  both deserve recognition.

The other counterpart is [Emaze](http://www.emaze.com)

Although emaze has other pricing plans, it can be used for free as stated in FAQ:

> Can I use emaze for free?
>
> Absolutely! We at emaze believe that everyone and anyone can and
>   should get their ideas heard and your free account is yours for life.

- 3D scenes to 2D slides
- Cloud-Based presentation
  software.
- automatic design

Answer (score 0):

There's also Impress.js that does some impressive presentions, including 3d effects :

http://impress.github.io/impress.js/#/bored

Answer (score 0):

There is Microsoft's [Sway](https://sway.com/).

This enables you to create interactive presentations.  The presentations can be hosted online and made publicly available.

The viewer controls their own progress through the presentation following any highlights and links that you provide.
As you would expect, it supports embedded videos, audio and other formats.

There are apps for all the usual platforms but I tend to just use it in a desktop browser.

It has a *How To* demonstration [here](https://sway.com/howtosway).