# Free software to create non-linear presentations with a free camera?

Tags: gratis, offline, cross-platform, presentation, wysiwyg

before anything else, I'm aware of this question: [Alternative to Prezi](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36082/alternative-to-prezi/42409#42409), and that this one partially overlaps with it. I hope it's not seen as a duplicate. If it is, my apologies in advance.

I'm looking for an application fullfilling the following criteria:

1-As the title mentions, I want to create non-linear presentations. This means the ability, from any given state of the presentation, to freely choose to move to one of a set of possible alternatives. I'm really interested in having this done by moving a camera, and zooming in and out like Prezi does.

2-I'd like the created presentations to be portable. This would mean either having the presentation viewer to be cross-platform or be webbrowser-based. However, I simultaneously require the presentation viewer (and if possible the presentation creator) to be useable offline.

3-I require the software to be free.

4-I require the editor to be WYSIWYG since my fluency in programming languages is limited, and have no extra time to invest on that ATM (however, having an optional programming interface would be nice for when, in the future, I make some time for learn whatever programming language is required).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [iMapping Tool](http://www.imapping.info/) could be right for you.

Like Prezi, it is based on deep zooming, but more focused on building structured Knowledge maps than on fancy presentation effects.

The iMapping Tool is classical, old-school, download, offline software.
It is available for Windows and Mac (and inofficially Linux).

There is a free version available that works with maps of up tp 300 items.
For bigger maps, there is a commercial version, which is also given away for free for charities and the like. Even for larger maps, the free version can act as a viewer / navigator.

The website is in German, while the tool itself is English. Just check out the video - you will get an impression.

Disclaimer: The iMapping tool is my own development and it is me who sells the  commercial version.